# Problemas no Sql usando Api do Google

Tags: javascript, sql

Antes de fazer essa pergunta procurei aqui e não achei o mesmo problema.
Eu uso o **Google Spreadsheet** como meu Banco de Dados e uso a biblioteca sheetrock + sql para acessar a planilha. Consigo retornar os dados mas acontece algo em particular.

Tenho os seguintes registros na tabela:

> ```
> id       Ano    mês      Data
> 1448    2018    maio    24/05/2018
> 1449    2018    maio    29/05/2018
> 1450    2018    maio    29/05/2018
> 1451    2018    maio    29/05/2018
> 1452    2018    maio    29/05/2018
> 1453    2018    junho   05/06/2018
> 1454    2018    junho   05/06/2018
> 1455    2018    junho   05/06/2018
> 1456    2018    junho   05/06/2018
> 1457    2018    junho   05/06/2018
> ```

Eu preciso todos os registros do mês de corrente (ex: junho) e do ano corrente (ex: 2018). Uso o seguinte SQL

```
var sqla = 'select * where  B = "' + [variável que pega o ano] +  '"' + ' and  E = "' +   [variável que pega o mês]  + '" order by A DESC ' ;
```

Mas quando uso **order by A DESC** ele não retorna o último registro **com o id 1457**. Se retiro o Order by ele retorna todos os registros. Mas, eu preciso que retorne os dados em ordem decrescente.

O que pode ser o meu error?? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual coluna seria a A?

Comment: o 'A' seria referente a primeira coluna ID

Comment: Coloca o select já como os valores das variáveis, pode ser o seu Where

Comment: Eu já fiz esse teste e retorna o mesmo problema.

Comment: Já tirou o where e continua o mesmo?

Comment: Quando retiro o where retorna todos os registros. Se o retiro o 'Order by A DESC' retorna todos os registros. Mas, usando Order by ASC ele retorna todos os registros.

Comment: Problema resolvido. Minha planilha tem mais de 70 colunas. Então, quando uso Select * ele não funciona. 
Mas se coloco todas as colunas o sql retorna todos os registro que quero.